# What does '@' mean in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, at-sign

I've tried googling but come up short. I am furthering my Haskell knowledge by reading some articles and I came across one that uses a syntax I've never seen before.
An example would be:

```
reconstruct node@(Node a b c l r) parent@(Node b d le ri)
```

I've never seen these @'s before. I tried searching online for an answer but came up short. Is this simply a way to embed tags to help make things clearer, or do they have an actual impact on the code?

Comment: Search for "as patterns" in http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions#pattern-matching for an introduction.

Comment: While traditional search engines won't return useful results when searching for special characters, Haskell's own [hoogle is usually quite useful](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%40) for such questions.

Comment: @ComicSansMS More helpful then the answer!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding the Haskell as-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27467650/understanding-the-haskell-as-pattern)

Comment: @ComicSansMS, it doesn't help when searching for syntax though.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It is used in pattern matching. Now `node` variable will refer to the entire `Node` data type for the argument `Node a b c l r`. So instead of passing to the function as `Node a b c l r`, you can use `node` instead to pass it up.

A much simpler example to demonstrate it:

```
data SomeType = Leaf Int Int Int | Nil deriving Show

someFunction :: SomeType -> SomeType
someFunction leaf@(Leaf _ _ _) = leaf
someFunction Nil = Leaf 0 0 0
```

The `someFunction` can also be written as:

```
someFunction :: SomeType -> SomeType
someFunction (Leaf x y z) = Leaf x y z
someFunction Nil = Leaf 0 0 0
```

See how simpler was the first version ?

Comment: Even simpler would be `someFunction leaf@Leaf{} = leaf`.

Comment: @AndrásKovács, but doesn't it require some explanations on `Leaf{}`?

Comment: The 2 are slightly different in ghci (in the second one it will re-apply the constructor arguments), but I'd be very surprised if that were the case in ghc compiled code

Comment: What does `@` mean in a context like `Proxy @Foo`?

Comment: Whew, finally figured out it needs `{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}`, still learning what it is though.

Comment: @Josh.F - In that context, it is some sort of type cast à la C/C++. I would expect your `Foo` thing to be a _type_. Formally, this @_type_ notation allows you to give explicit type arguments to a polymorphic function. Like: `let x = (read  @Integer  "33")` setting x to be an Integer object of value 33. [Details here](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/wikis/type-application).

Comment: @jpmarinier, no, it is not a type cast of any sort. It does indeed let you apply type arguments, but what those mean depend on the particular functions or methods involved.

Comment: @dfeuer I agree it is only a loose analogy, as a C/C++ _cast_ applies to a value, while this Haskell construct applies to a function, with for example the expression `(read @Integer)` having type `String -> Integer`. Please note I did not use the word _cast_ in my answer below.

Comment: @jpmarinier, it's so loose I can't even guess what it means. `foo @Int` could easily be a function that takes two characters and produces an `IO` action returning `()`.

Answer (score 12):

### Using @t as a type indicator

Besides the argument pattern matching usage described in the answer of @Sibi, in Haskell the "at" character ('@', also known as an [arobase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_sign) character) can be used in some contexts to **force a typing decision**. This is mentioned in the comments by @Josh.F.

This is **not** part of the default language features, and is known as the [Type Application](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/wikis/type-application) Haskell language extension. In summary, the extension allows you to give explicit type arguments to a polymorphic function such as `read`. In a classic .hs source file, the relevant pragma must be included:

```
{-#  LANGUAGE TypeApplications  #-}
```

### Example:

```
$ ghci
GHCi, version 8.2.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
 λ> 
 λ> let x = (read @Integer "33")

 <interactive>:4:10: error:
    Pattern syntax in expression context: read@Integer
    Did you mean to enable TypeApplications?
 λ> 
 λ> :set -XTypeApplications
 λ>
 λ> let x = (read @Integer "33")
 λ>
 λ> :type  x
 x :: Integer
 λ> 
 λ> x
 33
 λ>
```

### Further details

For the `read` polymorphic function, the type indicator introduced by `@` relates to the type of the result returned by `read`. But this is **not** generally true.

Generally speaking, you have to consider the type variables that appear in the *type signature* of the function at hand. For example, let's have a look at the `fmap` library function.

```
fmap :: Functor ft => (a -> b) -> ft a -> ft b
```

So here, we have 3 type variables, in order of appearance: ft, a, b. If we specialize `fmap` like this:

```
myFmap = fmap  @type1  @type2  @type3
```

then `type1` will relate to `ft`, `type2` will relate to `a` and `type3` will relate to `b`. Also, there is a special dummy type indicator `@_` which means: “*here, any type goes*”.

For example, we can force the output type of `fmap` to be `Integer` and the functor to be the plain list `[]`, leaving the input type `a` unspecified:

```
 λ> 
 λ> myFmap = fmap  @[]  @_  @Integer
 λ> 
 λ> :type myFmap
 myFmap :: (_ -> Integer) -> [_] -> [Integer]
 λ>
```

As for the `read` function, its type is:

```
read :: Read a => String -> a
```

So there is only room for one type indicator, and it relates to the type of the result returned by `read`, as displayed above.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking - I knew about @'s use in pattern matching, but not for type indication. Thanks!