# How do I use (@) operator in Haskell as I get parse error on input?

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell and I am trying to calculate the maximum segment sum,

```
(@) :: Int -> Int -> Int
x @ y = 0 `max` (x + y)

mss2 :: [Int] -> Int
mss2 = maximum . scanr (@) 0
```

The error is

`No Modules Loaded for (@)`

I found this snippet in Richard Bird's text.
What am I missing here?
Are there other ways to declare/overload the operators, is my approach wrong?

Comment: `x @ y = ...` doesn't mean what you think it does. `@` is being used as an [as-pattern](https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/patterns.html), not as a infix operator. Give `x @ [a,b] = [1,2]` a try, and then check `x`, `a`, and `b`.

Comment: Yes, `@` is in effect a reserved symbol. (It has special effect as 'type appllication' in advanced Haskell, for example.) I wouldn't try to use it as an ordinary operator.

Comment: I tried the above functions, instead of `@` I used `$` by hiding its the original implementation and it works just fine. So it means `@` is not an ordinary operator. Thank you for your help @Brian and @AntC

Comment: You can also try `@@`, `.@`, `@.`  or some other variation, but `@` is one of the reserved symbols, like `->` and `::`.

Comment: Related to [SO question 30326249](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30326249/what-does-mean-in-haskell).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that in the context of that book, `(@)` is being used as a stand-in for *some binary operator* such as `(+)` or `(<>)`, even though this is not actually legal Haskell syntax<sup>†</sup>.

For questions about Haskell syntax, it’s helpful to consult the [Haskell 2010 Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/).

In Ch. 2 *Lexical Structure*, under [§2.2 Lexical Program Structure](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch2.html#x7-160002.2), you can find `@` in the grammar of symbols that may appear in an operator name:

> *symbol*  →   *ascSymbol* | *uniSymbol*<sub>⟨*special* | `_` | `"` | `'`⟩</sub>
>
> *ascSymbol*   →    `!` | `#` | `$` | `%` | `&` | `⋆` | `+` | `.` | `/` | `<` | `=` | `>` | `?` | **`@`**
>     | `\` | `^` | `|` | `-` | `~` | `:`

And [§2.4 Lexical Structure: Identifiers and Operators](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch2.html#x7-180002.4) defines valid operator names to include such symbols:

> *varsym*  →   ( ***symbol***<sub>⟨`:`⟩</sub> {***symbol***} )<sub>⟨*reservedop* | *dashes*⟩</sub>
>
> *consym*  →   ( `:` {***symbol***} )<sub>⟨*reservedop*⟩</sub>

However, the subscript in angle brackets denotes a “difference” or exclusion, so this disallows a list of reserved identifiers. Under the production *reservedop* you can find that `@` appears in that list:

> *reservedop*     →   `..` | `:` | `::` | `=` | `\` | `|` | `<-` | `->` | **`@`** | `~` | `=>`

The reason is that the `@` symbol denotes an *“as” pattern*, described in [§3.17.2.8 Informal Semantics of Pattern Matching](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-580003.17):

> 8. Matching an as-pattern *var@apat* against a value *v* is the result of matching *apat* against *v*, augmented with the binding of *var* to *v*.

*As* patterns are very useful for controlling the sharing of values and making certain definitions more concise, e.g.:

```
-- | Merge two sorted lists.
merge :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a] -> [a]

-- ‘as0’ & ‘bs0’ denote the original input lists.
-- ‘as’ & ‘bs’ denote their tails.

merge as0@(a : as) bs0@(b : bs) = case compare a b of

  -- ‘as0’ passes along the same list cell;
  -- repeating ‘a : as’ would allocate a /new/ cell.

  GT -> b : merge as0 bs
  _  -> a : merge as  bs0

merge [] bs0 = bs0
merge as0 [] = as0
```

Therefore, the definition:

```
x @ y = 0 `max` (x + y)
```

Or more conventionally written `x@y = …`, is equivalent to defining two variables referring to the same value, which furthermore is defined recursively:

```
x = 0 `max` (x + y)
y = x
```

Without the type signature `Int -> Int -> Int`, this definition would be accepted, defining `x, y :: (Ord a, Num a) => a`, but attempting to evaluate either variable would produce an infinite loop, since this is “unproductive” recursion.

The solution is to use a non-reserved symbol as your operator name instead, such as `<@>` or `+.`.

<sup>†</sup> I can’t find a citation for this, but it’s *possible* that GHC *used to* accept this syntax, even though it was also disallowed by the [Haskell 98 Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/) which was current at the time the first edition of this book came out, and that this example code just wasn’t updated for the second edition.