# Loop a function 10 times in Haskell

Tags: function, loops, haskell

Do you have any idea how I can loop the function `func2` 10 times

```
type Vertex = Int
type OutNeighbors = [Vertex]
data Graph = Graph [(Vertex,OutNeighbors)] deriving (Eq, Show, Read)

func2 (Graph g) = filter (\x -> contains (fst x) (func1 (Graph g))) g   --I need to repeat this function 10 times.
```

I am kind of new to haskell and I have no idea how to do loops

Comment: Have you tried to write a recursive function?

Comment: `func2_10 = foldr1 (.) . replicate 10 (Graph . func2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do you have any idea how I can loop the function `func2` 10 times

You could [`iterate`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#v:iterate) it and [`!!`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#v:-33--33-) at 10:

```
> take 5 $ iterate ("hi " ++) "there!"
["there!","hi there!","hi hi there!","hi hi hi there!","hi hi hi hi there!"]

> let func2 = (+3) in iterate func2 0 !! 10
30
```

but that would require `func2` to return the same type as its input, and right now it appears to have type

```
func2 :: Graph -> [(Vertex,OutNeighbors)]
```

But if you wrapped `Graph` back onto it, i.e.,

```
func2 :: Graph -> Graph
func2 (Graph g) = Graph (... g)
```

then you could `iterate` on it.

Comment: `func2 :: Graph -> Graph` this leads to an error (Couldn't match expected type `Graph' with actual type `[(Vertex, Types.OutNeighbors)]')

Comment: @karmo20 you also have to insert the `Graph` constructor in `func2` between the `=` and the `filter` and add parentheses around the `filter ... g` part. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In Haskell you can use recursion for loops, here is an example:

```
myLoop 0 g = g
myLoop n g = myLoop (n - 1) (Graph (func2 g))
```

Now calling `myLoop 10 g` will call `func2` 10 times on `g`.

Note that I had to wrap the result back in the `Graph` type, that is probably something you should do in the `func2` function:

```
func2 (Graph g) = Graph (filter (\x -> contains (fst x) (func1 (Graph g))) g)
```

You can get a little bit higher-level if you wrap this up in the `State` monad from the `transformers` package:

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.State.Lazy (execState, modify)
import Control.Monad (replicateM_)

myLoop :: Int -> Graph -> Graph
myLoop n g = execState (replicateM_ n (modify func2)) g
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one of these situations where, in order to avoid typing errors, you need to be able to refer to *both* the whole parameter and to its subcomponents thru proper names.

Fortunately, Haskell provides just that. This is known as the “**as patterns**”. More details here: [SO-q30326249](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30326249/what-does-mean-in-haskell).

In your case, you could note your graph parameter as: `g@(Graph(pairs))`. Then, `g` is your graph object, and `pairs` is the corresponding list of type `[(Vertex,OutNeighbors)]`.

You do not tell us about your `contains` function, but it is possible to infer that its type is:

```
contains :: Vertex -> Graph -> Bool
```

With that in mind, a version of your graph function taking an arbitrary iteration count can be written this way:

```
type Vertex = Int
type OutNeighbors = [Vertex]
data Graph = Graph [(Vertex,OutNeighbors)]  deriving  (Eq, Show, Read)

funcN :: Int -> Graph -> Graph
funcN  iterCount  g@(Graph(pairs)) =
    if (iterCount <= 0)  then  g  -- nothing to do
                         else  let
                                   gm1 = funcN (iterCount - 1) g     -- recursion
                                   fn  = \(v,ngs) -> contains v gm1  -- filtration
                               in
                                   Graph (filter fn pairs)
```

Using the same techniques, a tentative version of the `contains` function could be like this:

```
contains :: Vertex -> Graph -> Bool
contains v g@( Graph [] )                 =  False
contains v g@( Graph ((v0,ngs0):pairs) )  =  (v == v0)  ||  contains v (Graph(pairs))
```

This second function is a bit more complicated, because lists can be described thru 2 patterns, empty and non-empty.

Finally, a version of the function that does exactly 10 iterations can be written like this:

```
func10 :: Graph -> Graph
func10 g = funcN 10 g
```

or also in a more concise fashion using *partial application* (known in Haskell circles as [currying](https://wiki.haskell.org/Currying)):

```
func10 :: Graph -> Graph
func10 = funcN 10
```

### Addendum: library style, using *nest*:

If for some reason “manual recursion” is frowned upon, it is possible to use instead the [`nest :: Int -> (a -> a) -> a -> a`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/utility-ht-0.0.16/docs/Data-Function-HT.html#v:nest) library function. It computes the Nth compositional power of a function, using recursion internally.

Then one just has to write the single iteration version of the graph function. The code looks like this:

```
import Data.Function.HT  (nest)

funcNl :: Int -> Graph -> Graph
funcNl iterCount g0 = let
                        -- 2 local function definitions:
                        ftfn g1 (v, ngs)        =  contains v g1
                        func1 g2@(Graph(pairs)) =  Graph (filter (ftfn g2) pairs)
                      in
                        nest iterCount func1 g0
```